# Vuex: Propogate response to sibling components

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I have turned several axios requests made by application from 3 sibling components into one. So this query now brings back all the information in one simple request. Trouble is I'm not sure architecturally, ***where it makes sense to perform the request, store the data and propogate the response to the three sibling components***.

Should I store the response in an application-Level shared state ? Also then how do I propogate the response, to these 3 sibling comnponents using Vuex?

Answer (score 1):

if it is critical data then you might want to request it in Vuex `nuxtServerInit` action and save it in vuex state using `commit`. [Read more](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

That way your app will receive the info once when it renders on server & can be used from any page or component using `vuex getters`.